# Reference the secrets manager Id in another serverless yaml file

Tags: aws-glue, serverless, aws-secrets-manager

Given I have the following Secret defined in my Serverless Yaml file:  How do I reference the secret id (arn?) in another yaml file where I am adding a connection to Glue Connection

```
  RedshiftCredentials:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: redshiftCredentials
      Description: "Dynamically set password on secret"
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "analytics"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 20
        ExcludePunctuation: true
      Tags:
        - Key: "RedshiftCredentials"
          Value: "Use this to connect to database"
```